# Online booking system with php

Tags: php, mysql

Im looking for any tutorial for online booking and reservation using php and mysql. I cant find so much from google.

Comment: If the tutorial is supposed to tell you how to make the entire application, what will be left for you to do?

Comment: Im looking for any edifice. nusbit gave me a good link for case study. (Im sure that you know what is case-study) .It can be a good book or case study from great programmers. Dont heat please ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about to build your own system or search for an existing booking system and studying this ?

-> http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpreservation/
-> http://php.brickhost.com/

Comment: @nusbit;
Thanks alot for case study link.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest learning more about PHP and MySQL first, and using that knowledge to create your own app.  Here are some good resources for beginning PHP and MySQL knowledge.

http://www.w3schools.com

http://www.tizag.com

Comment: I know this sites. Im looking for advanced topics not beginning. 
(online booking)

Comment: 'online booking' isn't a topic - its an application. An advanced topic might be "design patterns" not "how to build X application".

Comment: if you already know the languages, you shouldn't need a tutorial on building an application, you should just need to get certain specific questions answered.  What exactly about online booking systems are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Erik took the words right out of my mouth...

Comment: I usually direct questions like this to rentacoder.com but I'm feeling slightly less snarky today then usual.

Comment: These php tutorials (in above link) are very poor in security. Im looking only for tutorial. Take it easy guys ;)

Comment: So you are looking for a tutorial on Security?  that is different from a tutorial on Online Booking...

Comment: No;
But http://www.w3schools.com and 
http://www.tizag.com tutorials are very poor in security. Please dont suggest this links to anyone. Programmers may learn writting secure code from beginning!

Answer (score 3):

Even though this is an old post, I would like to give my opinion.

It is possible to build a PHP and MySQL online booking system.

The hardest part I think of building one is date programming.

Best solution is build a flow chart IPO chart, and write notes.

The way I solve this is by dividing tables in mySQL, one for the actual product, the 2nd for block dates.

The third is for allotments and features.

There after you would need to create mysql query for three tables and connect the product table with the blocks, and allotments.

Once you do that you would have to create a form, and the hardest part is establishing a query, or basically code up the search to get the results you need based upon the three tables you created, make sure that the primary ID for the product table is posted in the other two tables so the primary ID can be identified when the query of the search result post.

Its like building a simple shopping cart + a bit of logic builds booking system.

Warn you if you develop alone, it takes months. Beleave me. Im up to four months, * 8 hour days. 
But its working for me. 
Also, javaScript or should I say jQuery helps on some features of booking engines.

Comment: I share your pain Michael! :) I recently created a meeting room scheduler and it took me a staggering 4 months to get to a 'passable,' application. Once you get into calendar days and recurrence, depending on just how deep the rabbit hole is intended to go; it can be daunting and definitely not meant for a beginner by any means. I'm no Jedi, but even with a few solid years programming, this kind of thing made me sick. Just thought id comment on this as the struggle is most definitely real! :)